# How to restore migration history with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Let's say I have a database which is created by three migrations. They can be seen in the table `dbo._EFMigrationsHistory` and the content could look like this:

```
MigrationId                         ProductVersion
20200516181941_InitialMigration     3.1.4
20200517091058_AddedIndexes         3.1.4
20200605115456_IntroducedBreweries  3.1.4
```

Now let's say that I for some reason lose all of the table (or just a part of it). So suddenly the table look like this:

```
MigrationId                         ProductVersion
20200517091058_AddedIndexes         3.1.4
20200605115456_IntroducedBreweries  3.1.4
```

And then I make a new migration, because i changed something in the database

```
Add-Migration SomethingChanged
```

This will work fine, since we aren't talking to the database at this point. But if I try to update the database, like this

```
Update-Database
```

It will fail, because it it trying to re-run the `InitialMigration` (or at least so I assume). So a common error is that the tables created in the InitialMigration cannot be created, because they already exist.

During development you can simply nuke the database and/or migrations, but that's not a very viable strategy for production. It can also be done with `Script-Migration`, which has a from/to option, allowing something like this:

```
Script-Migration 20200517091058_AddedIndexes 20200605115456_IntroducedBreweries
```

But this doesn't seem to work on `Update-Database` (not in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs#update-the-database) either).

Is there any (production safe) way to fix this, so that the migration history isn't broken for all eternity?

The best way I can think of, is to manually insert the missing row(s) in the database, but this seems quite hack-ish...

Comment: The best way you can think of sounds best to me :) Somehow the row in migrations table got deleted, presumably not by any `update-database` calls, so you need to restore it somehow as you would restore any data in database - manual insert is ok. I'm assuming the migrations files are under version control so you know what you need to insert. Also if you use `script-migration from to` you'll get an sql file which you can simply execute without the need to call `update-database`

Answer (score 4):

The Issue: You have mucked up your migrations and you would like to reset it without deleting your existing tables.

The Problem: You can't reset migrations with existing tables in the database as EF wants to create the tables from scratch.

What to do:

1. Delete existing migrations from Migrations_History table.
2. Delete existing migrations from the Migrations Folder.
3. Run add-migration Reset. This will create a migration in your
   Migration folder that includes creating the tables (but it will not
   run it so it will not error out.)
4. You now need to create the initial row in the MigrationHistory table
   so EF has a snapshot of the current state. EF will do this if you
   apply a migration. However, you can't apply the migration that you
   just made as the tables already exist in your database. So go into
   the Migration and comment out all the code inside the "Up" method.
5. Now run update-database. It will apply the Migration (while not
   actually changing the database) and create a snapshot row in
   MigrationHistory.

You have now reset your migrations and may continue with normal migrations.

Comment: On another note, without database backups you can't "restore" the migration history. If you deleted something and don't have backups you are just going to have to reset them in order to continue using EF. Hope this helps.

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler/cleaner solution, but I guess you cannot win every time :-). The dependency on the migration history seems to be a bit of a weak spot for EF Core. But thanks for your answer, even if it's not what I hoped for.

Comment: Yes I am sorry, there is no real way to fix this without a backup. This is the only way if you have messed up that table. I tend to run a script after I do my EF migrations to backup just that table to avoid situations like this. If you don't mind too marking mine as correct too :) I am trying to be more active in community now that I actually know a thing or two. Also you really should never touch this table, so I'd be more concerned with how a migration row was removed. You should always use EF to backout migrations and what not to avoid problems like this and never touch it directly.

Comment: Saved my day! thank you! for me the code didn't match the last migration to a test environment and wanted to make that as my benchmark migration and go on from there...